# How to exclude from another QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have query:

```
users_to_exclude = MyModel.objects.filter(status=1)
```

and now:

```
result = MyAnotherModel.objects.filter(image=my_image).count()
```

and:

```
result = MyAnotherModel.objects.filter(image=my_image).exclude(user__in=users_to_exclude).count()
```

shows me the same number (`users_to_exclude` have properly data). How to do it well?

Comment: `user_to_exclude` what type is it?

Comment: `MyModel.objects.filter(status=1)` return type is `MyModel` queryset. What `exclude(user__in=users_to_exclude)` is expecting is a queryset of User Types. Hence the issue. Does `MyModel` have a user object in it ?

Comment: show the models definitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read that topic:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

and there is:

```
You can also use a queryset to dynamically evaluate the list of values instead of providing a list of literal values:
```